# Notation clarification: two vectors side by side in momentum equation (Euler equations / Navier Stokes)

Tags: notation, vectors, fluid-dynamics

I'm back in mathematics / fluids after a fairly long break and feeling rusty. In the context of the Euler equations  I sometimes see

$$
\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot \left(\rho \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U} \right)
$$

I'm not sure what the correct interpretation of this notation is. I don't think its  an implicit dot product (must be a vector inside the brackets?), nor is it a cross product ($\mathbf{U}\times\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{0}$).

You'd think this would be something I could look up, but apparently I didn't have much luck formulating the right search term to turn something useful up. I know this is likely a stupid / elementary question, so I 'd appreciate someone spelling it out for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bit unusual but I expect it's the outer product $UU^T$, which is a square matrix. Then $\nabla\cdot$ is the tensor divergence, $(\nabla\cdot A)_i=\sum dA_{ij}/dx_j$.

Comment: Hi Rahul. I worked the terms through and have verified that it must be as you say - the outer product of $UU^T$ gives what I expect. Thanks, you've helped put me on the right track and save a bit stress :) . I think I'm going to have to brush up on tensors and more sophisticated notation than just the standard vector calculus!